# WP7.5 Mango Tile BackContent alignment

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to center-align the BackContent of a tile?

For example: 
54"
2-2

I want the above two lines aligned centered on the back side of a tile. Is this possible?

Sample: http://www.silverlightshow.net/Storage/Users/AndreaBoschin/__Capture.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a image, where it's aligned, and use that as a back property. I've written a [guide](http://windcape.posterous.com/how-to-live-tile-with-scheduled-agent) about it.

(For the front tile, but the backtile is no different).

Answer (score 2):

You have to draw the text manually onto your BackBackgroundImage as you cannot adjust the placement of the BackContent.

> It is not possible to update your Tile with animations or sound. **The
>   placement of the Tile properties is not customizable.**

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Edit: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028889/dynamic-livetile-adding-background-image/8031300#8031300), there is example code showing how to do it.